# Bijections and Visual Representations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

Throughout math we learn about the cardinality of sets. We learn that the existence of a bijection between two sets imply that the cardinality of these two sets are equal. For each set there is similar to a picture we can draw to represent it. For example, when drawing the set $\mathbb{R}$ we often draw a straight line.

That brings me to my question:

Let us say that we have a bijection $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow A$ for some set $A$. Does this mean we can represent $A$ as a real line as well? It seems that anything that holds for $\mathbb{R}$ should hold for $A$, however that might not be the case.

If this is not true for a bijection, then is it true for two groups that are isomorphic? Or maybe there is another term that I am unaware of that denotes we can represent two sets as the same picture?

Comment: I think it can be represented as a straight line as $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ have the same cardinality. But, there's a tiny problem that it doesn't mean that the set is dense. So, we cannot guarantee if it is a straight line, not just a bunch of points. But, for easy visualization, I think it should work.

Comment: Okay it seems that I have to be very careful if I were to represent it as a line, since I would just be showing that each element pairs with another element in the other set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we depict $\mathbb{R}$ as a straight line, we're usually not just thinking of it as a *set*, we're thinking of it as a *space*: it comes equipped with a huge amount of extra structure, such a notion of distance, arithmetic operations, and so on.

Bijections don't preserve all this structure, they simply preserve the number of elements. For example, there is a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, but $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ doesn't retain the same structure as $\mathbb{R}$. You could, if you wanted to, depict $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ as a line, but the line wouldn't have any meaning in the usual sense.

However, there are generalisations of the notion of a bijection that might get at what you want. For example:

- If $X$ is a metric space (i.e. a set equipped with a notion of distance), then a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to X$ that preserves the distance is called a (global) [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry);
- If $X$ is a topological space (i.e. a set equipped with a notion of *nearness*, which is a bit weaker than distance), then a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to X$ that preserves this structure is called a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism);
- If $X$ is a ring or a field (i.e. a set equipped with a notion of arithmetic), then a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to X$ that preserves all the arithmetic operations is called a ring (or field) [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism).

In the first two cases (where we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a certain kind of space), the set $X$ will in some sense look like a line.

Comment: Okay that is very helpful! So I'm guessing as long as our picture represents these three properties we can represent it as a line. Also if $X$ has a picture we can represent $\mathbb{R}$ in a different way as well. Also does it preserve ordering or relations?

Comment: @TJLockwood: A bijection between set with a notion of order that preserves the order relation is called an [order-isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism). Whenever you have a notion of sets equipped with a certain kind of structure, this usually comes with a notion of a kind of function that preserves the structure. This is studied in the abstract in the field of [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), where 'objects' play the role of sets-with-structure and 'morphisms' play the role of structure-preserving functions.